# Using log parser in C# without installing it?

Tags: c#, logparser

I am creating website in which i am using log parser to parser some kind of log. I can only use the log parser when i installed in my machine. When run my project on another machine without installing log parser i am getting the below exception

[image]

I can see logparser.dll in my my installation folder (program files)but i could not able to refer this DLL.it show the error that it is not valid assembly or COM component.Please refer my screenshot

[image]

How can i run my project on any machine without installing log parser Exe ? Please help me ?

Comment: Are you distributing the DLL of the Parser with your application?

Comment: You need to copy & register the logparser.dll

Comment: @fk2,@Alex K i have update my question .Please refer it.

Answer (score 3):

I was probably a bit unclear with my comment to add the appropriate dll, so I'll try again:

LogParser was written/last updated in 2005, which is why it only offers support for COM-style deployment. To do this install LogParser, then in your Visual Studio Solution go to References -> Right-Click to Add References -> COM and check "MS Utility 1.0 Type Library - Log Parser Interfaces". Make sure that the file version matches your version of LogParser (2.2.10.0). After doing that your references section of your solution should contain an entry named MSUtil. In that entry set "Embed Interop Types" to true if you are using C# 4.0 or greater, otherwise set the proper deployment options (copy etc.).

If you are using C# 4.0 or upwards you also have to change the way you instantiate classes, because embedded types don't need the "class"-notation that COM had before. What this means is that you have to delete a class from your init-code, meaning

`COMFileSystemInputContextClass inputFormat = new COMFileSystemInputContextClassClass();` turns into

`COMFileSystemInputContextClass inputFormat = new COMFileSystemInputContextClass();`

and so on. I just tried this and got it to run.

Comment: Can you able to work on different machine with same project but without installing log parser?

Comment: That depends on what you mean with work. You should be able to deploy your application without installing log parser on the client machine, yes. However if you're thinking about developing/compiling your project without installing log parser, I doubt that would be possible. Not only do the EULAs forbid you from making your own redistributables of it, you also have to get the COM-components to Visual Studio somehow.